# Why is Wi-Fi data transfer slow?

Tags: wireless-networking

I have a Wi-Fi router which was attached with my modem, and the PC was connected to the Wi-Fi router through an Ethernet cable.

Yesterday I moved my modem and router to another room and connected my PC with Wi-Fi through an external Wi-Fi USB dongle (TP-LINK TL-WN722N).

I noticed that the file transfer speed from my cell to PC via Wi-Fi is greatly affected.  It's not clear to me why is this happening because although PC is now connected through Wi-Fi but the dongle supports more than 54Mbps which is still enough.

Comment: Distance from Wi-Fi signal source affects signal quality. Signal quality affects connection speed.

Comment: Check [this article](http://superuser.com/questions/763403/why-is-wifi-data-transfer-is-slow) what affects Wi-Fi signal.

Comment: The distance is not a problem I think because a pc closer to the router shows same behaviour

Comment: What was the speed before? What is the speed now? How are you testing? (Are you measuring Internet speed? Are you measuring local transfers?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although internet speeds are not the fastest, and it is possible that the wifi connection is faster than the internet, because of several factors I'll describe below, wifi is always going to slow down internet a little bit.

A few factors can slow down the connection:

1. **The signal strength**: If your signal is weak, you simply don't get the fastest speed. Even though the wifi supports 54Mbps, you'll get lower. The lower the signal strength, the slower things become.
2. **Distance**: The closer you are to the wifi point, the stronger the signal is. That also means that if you move further away, the signal is weaker, and as such the the connection becomes slower (see point 1)
3. **Things blocking the signal**: In buildings, things such as walls and floors block the signal. Although it is not much blocking and the signal goes through, it will block the signal. If the wall or floor has any metal in it, it will block the signal more than if it doesn't. This too affects the signal strength (see point 1)
4. **Wrong Channel**: When you configure your Wifi connection, you usually have to set a channel. Many people use wifi nowadays, and if you set your wifi to a channel where other wifi signals are too, they will start battling eachother which affects the signal strength. (see point 1).
5. **Misconfigured router**: If the router is not configured properly, either through its settings or by hardware (antenna's not pointing up) it can slow down the connection too, even though you seem to have a strong signal.

There are routers that use more antenna's and special techniques to increase the speed and signal strength. These routers are expensive though. In any case, if you can use a wired connection, always do so unless performance is not an issue.

Comment: The thing is it is a remote area and I don't have any more wifi signals in area other than mine and the distance is barely a few feets and as stated earlier I tried it with another pc just next to wifi router but connected via wifi usb dongle and still problem persists

Comment: Yes, but as my first line, Wifi is always slower than through a cable. But I'll edit my point and add some more info.